# Adding a decorator to an abstract method

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, abstract-methods

I'm trying to add a decorator on an abstractmethod such that when the method is called in the subclasses, the decorator function is also called. This is for a framework, so I'm trying to limit the amount of extra code later users have to code. The decorator is pretty specific to the framework and isn't meant to be used by the general users of the framework - hope that makes sense.

I know there are a few other ways of doing this, but most of them involve the user copying some boilerplate code when they create their own subclasses. The decorator helps prevent having to copy the boilerplate.

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

def prepost(fn):
    # The new function the decorator returns
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("In wrap 1")
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
        print("In wrap 2")
        return
    wrapper.__isabstractmethod__ = True
    return wrapper

class Base(ABC):
    pass

class Foo(Base):
    @prepost
    @abstractmethod
    def dosomething(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Bar(Foo):
    def dosomething(self):
        print("I'm doing something")

Test = Bar()
Test.dosomething()
```

When I try this I just get:
I'm doing something

rather than the extra output from the decorator.

Comment: Right, because you overrode it.

Comment: The decorator doesn't apply to anything named `dosomething`, just the function it immediately decorates.

Comment: [PEP487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/) maybe. Decorators are not inherited, so you want to go the metaclass route. This PEP should provide a simpler alternative to "full-blown" metaclasses.